# Prevent Temp user creation in windows

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, user-profiles, user-management

Windows creating temp profile every time when I login to the PC. The pc has more than one user. I am facing this problem in many Windows 10 and Server 2012 PC's. The temp profile creation is not found in every user. But, in most of the cases it is there.

The Windows 10 is the free upgraded version. Initially, the case was less. Now recently the frequency of the error is increased.

Sometimes this will be solved if I log off and log in again. But, after 2-3 days again this repeats.

Installed Antivirus software: Symantec Endpoint Security, Norton Security and in some PCs Windows Defender.

I have also tried by removing all the services from ‘Services.msc’. But, not solved. I was using Windows 8 and 8.1 as Desktop OS previously and same software and hardware were being used in that also. But, this error was not found before.

Tried solutions: Searched in the internet about the error and found some solutions but none of them worked for me.

1. Contacted Microsoft support and they tried doing disk cleanup of C drive.
2. Deleted the temp created folder and changed the temp profile created in the registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList.
3. Enabled the "Do not log users on with temporary profiles" in the group policy as mensioned in Disable temporary user profile on workstations in a Windows 2008 env

All the steps done above did not work instead when I did the 3rd solution I got error when logging in saying "User Profile Service failed the sign-in. User Profile cannot be loaded." Now when I search for this error I got the same result as above mentioned options in Google.

Please help to solve this error and prevent from happening in the future.

**Update:**

When the OS creates the temp profile I can see 2 logs written in event viewer, which says:

1. Windows has backed up this user profile. Windows will automatically try to use the backup profile the next time this user logs on.
2. Windows cannot find the local profile and is logging you on with a temporary profile. Changes you make to this profile will be lost when you log off.

**Update 2**:

After disc clean in windows 10, the error stopped since from 2 days but don't know whether it is the correct solution.

Below steps are done in Windows server 2012 r2.

- We can rule out the antivirus, because tried by uninstalling antivirus but temp profile error still repeated.
- Deleted one user and created new profile for him but after 2 days the error repeated.

Comment: Test with both on a freshly installed **Windows Server 2012** and **Windows 10** OS with no `Symantec Endpoint Security nor Norton Security` having ever been installed, and fully apply all **Windows Updates**, and then try logging into the machine. Are you machines with this issues now all based off the same images or what? Are these domain-joined machines and are you signing onto a domain account or a local account? Stop fighting this and start with a fresh clean install of the OS to be sure and don't install anything; something is causing this.

Comment: Are saying that you're running both Symantec Endpoint Security and Norton Security installed onto the same machines? That could be a problem if so... I would expect the #2 `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` registry key deletion followed by a reboot and then log back on to fix the `~Windows cannot find the local profile` error so I'd double, triple, quadruple check that again!!

Comment: @MagicallyDelicous - The systems are not domain joined, they are in single workgroup. No there is only one antivirus in one system. I am facing the problem in multiple system which contains Symantech in some systems and Norton in some.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this issue in some computer, I'll try to explain what I understood of this issue:

1. Initially you are correctly logged on with a user X on the computer.
2. Then you logout.
3. When you log in again with user X, something doesn't works, and windows create a temp profile.

What is happening is that some of the files that windows use to manage use X informations, remaine "locked" during the logout (step 2 of the list).
At step 3 windows try to open these files... but they are already locked/in use by other process, so Windows show and error create a temp user profile.

I don't know why those files remain locked, when they shouldn't.
I don't even know which are the files that remain locked.

If Windows have the "Fast Startup" enabled, this issue may happen even after a reboot.

**Here is what worked for me on normal PC** (*I never tried on a server*)

- Disable Windows fast startup ( [google is your friend :-)](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&q=how%20to%20disable%20windows%2010%20%22fast%20startup%22&oq=how%20to%20disable%20windows%2010%20%22fast%20startup%22) )
- then log off the user
- then reboot Windows

If the above steps are not enough, **only on a normal computer (NOT on a server)**, you can try to:

- Log off the current user without turning off the computer
- Then unplug the power cable when the computer is still powered on (**DON'T do this on a server**)

**Keep in mind that unplugging the power from a server while it's running could be very bad**.
Unplugging a normal computer usually wont do any arm, **but unplugging a server with RAID Disk could trigger a Raid rebuild, and this is very bad, will lower the server performance, and will take a lot of time, and could require special maintenance procedure... and could also harm the service running on the server**.

Now that the "don't do this on a server" is out of the way, the reasoning behind the unplugging the running PC is that it will guarantee you that Windows will do a clean boot, without any cached information. This usually clean the "locked status" on those locked files, that prevent the logon of your user.

Comment: thanks for the reply. 'Fast Startup' is already disabled in all the PCs. In order to rule out the permission i just gave the full permission for C:\users folder to the 'User' group. But the temp profile was still creating. Strange thing i found that after the reboot of the server last night the temp profile of all the users created was auto corrected by windows when the users logged in this morning. But  still need to check for 2 days whether the error still occur or not.

Comment: On the server, if a reboot does help, maybe you can schedule a night-time reboot every day...